# Индексация страниц с товарами на сайте

Tags: php, mysql, seo

Есть интернет-магазин, все товары хранятся в *БД*, а не на отдельных страницах.

Но через поисковик нельзя найти тот или иной товар.

Нужно, чтобы введя запрос "iphone 5s white", можно было увидеть ссылку и, перейдя по ней, получить страницу с этим товаром, у которой в адресной строке имеется похожий *get*-запрос: `site.ru/product.php?id=564`

Каким образом реализуется подобное?

Answer (score 1):

Напишите авто генератор карты сайта, по правилам - [официальные правила](http://www.sitemaps.org/ru/protocol.html#index). Он создаст xml файл который без проблем "кушается" поисковиками.

Comment: А как это работает?

т.е. нужно создать карту сайта со всеми товарами??

а если товаров 2 млн.?

Comment: напишите авто генератор, по правилам просто. Он создаст xml файл который без проблем "кушается" поисковиками

Comment: @jedayka, внесите, пожалуйста, информацию из комментария в сам ответ, нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: изменил ответ, а так же добавил ссылку